# asp:TextBox - override Text property

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

How do I override the TextBox property "Text" (getter)  ?

Comment: Override?  You want to take over the getter of the `Text` property of the pre-existing `TextBox` control so that you can presumably return content distinct from what the control actually considers its text content?  Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.text.aspx) the property is virtual so you should be able to override like so:

```
class MyTextBox : TextBox {
 public override string Text 
{
 get { return /* return what you wish*/; }
 set { /**/ }
}
}
```

You can also override one of the Render methods to have full control of generated HTML. Though perhaps you had something else in mind?